# jquery ID select depending on user click of URL

Tags: jquery, onclick, capture

Here is Mycode:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#myLink1").click(function(){
            Foo Bar...

        });
    });

<a href = "#" id="myLink1"> click my Link <a>

<a href = "#" id="myLink2"> click my Link2 <a>

<a href = "#" id="myLink3"> click my Link3 <a>
```

for the first one fine, instead of repeating code, how can i capture what user clicked, for say if user clicked 2 or 3 #mylink1 has to be some how replaced is there any generic way??? please help me

Comment: Yes, there is: what do you want to happen when the user clicks one of the other links?

Comment: See this example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IBHzh

Answer (score 2):

Use the id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".your-class").click(function(){
     alert(this.id);
  });
});

<a href = "#" class="your-class" id="myLink1"> click my Link </a>
<a href = "#" class="your-class" id="myLink2"> click my Link2 </a>
<a href = "#" class="your-class" id="myLink3"> click my Link3 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without adding a class to your links, you can do this with an id selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id*="myLink"]').click(function() {
        //Function Code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".your-class").click(function(){
     // stuff here
   });
});

<a href="#" class="your-class" id="myLink1">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="your-class" id="myLink2">Link2</a>
<a href="#" class="your-class" id="myLink3">Link3</a>
```

Comment: And how does that answer the question?

Comment: @DavidThomas he wants to know how he can apply the event without having to do it for each ID. That's pretty much everyones understanding of the question so far.

Comment: The problem is that the question isn't clear, you've suggested adding a class and using that class to attach a click-handler. This *may* answer the question, but I'm not convinced what the question is, which makes this (and other) answer(s) somewhat spurious and speculative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
            Foo Bar...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give all your a tags the same class, and then change your jquery selector to

```
$('.yourClass').click(function(){
    $(this).whatYouWantToDo()
});
```

So $(this) will refer to only the one that was clicked.